# Ordnance Survey data on GeoServer 2.x

Tags: web-mapping, geoserver, ordnance-survey, geowebcache

Has anyone had any success deploying the Ordnance Survey's free datasets on its open sourced OSGBWebMapTools framework using GeoServer 2.0.2?

I've been able to set up the datasets on GeoServer 1.7.6 and would prefer for it to use the out of the box caching that GeoServer 2.x supports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GeoServer should upgrade seamlessly from 1.7.x to 2.0.x (or even 2.1.x) - to be on the safe side I'd make sure you have a copy of your data directory in case something goes wrong. Then simply install the latest version and restart. The only thing that I always forget is to download new plugin jars for any of the additional datastores and addons.

Comment: Thanks. I did try installing on 2.0.2 but after that failed I tried 1.7.6 which worked. In the 1.7.x version, configuration of the datastores and namespaces was done in the catalog.xml file. This is perhaps different in the 2.0.x version. I guess I have to figure where the configuration (manual xml based) is set in 2.0.x.

Comment: When the new version starts it will automatically reformat the old configuration file.

Answer (score 4):

Not me but Adrian Walker has

'Using Ordnance Survey OpenData Street View Rasters With GeoServer'

http://www.adrianwalker.org/2010/08/using-ordnance-survey-open-data-street.html

Some good tips there (especially if on linux platform)

Some python code is available at the bottom.

Or are you looking for Vector examples?
http://blog.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/2010/06/the-geoclinic/

Comment: Thanks, I came across both links in my initial research and remember them being quite useful. However, I decided to use this link (http://osgbwebmaptools.sourceforge.net/OSGBWebMapTools.html), which worked well for me except that I would have preferred it to work with 2.0.x (see comments below on iant's response). For now, just trying to serve rasters but will definitely look at some vector data in the near future.